# Session Disappearing After Leaving Domain - Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, session

With the Zend Framework, I have a problem with my sessions disappearing when I simply navigate away my domain, and then come back to it, but don't have any problems when going between pages on my own site.

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved the problem (seemingly), by just clearing the cache in my browser. But I'd like to know why it works when I do that?

Thanks